# ElasticSearch: Get the path of a top hit aggregation to reuse value for an other aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to use top hit aggregation and have access to the value of the field i got from it (toto here) in order to use it as input of my bucket script aggregation.
i don't find the path to have access to toto, for example this doesn't work, would you have any clue?

```
      "aggs": {
        "agg_hit": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "toto"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        },
        "agg_scr": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "toto": "agg_hit.toto"
              "other_params": "other_params"
            },
            "script": "toto*...."
          }
        }}
```

Comment: subaggregation are not allowed for top hits. Check this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16537 . Can you explain your issue, There may be work around

Comment: i am doing a term aggregation on a field A, and i want to have a sub aggregation (a bucket script) which has for parameters  a field B from the doc. For each bucket of my term aggregation on field A, each doc has the same value for the field B, so currently, to get this value, I am using a max aggregation, but i wanted to use top hits in order to improve the performance

Comment: what are you going to do in bucket_Script?

Comment: i am doing different things actually because i have this usecase multiple times.. 
maybe i was not clear enough about my problem: I am doing first a term aggregation on the id of one of my object, then inside my term aggregation i want to use other fields of  this object for my bucket script aggregation. Top Hits was (with max metrics) one of the idea i have to retrieve those field, but maybe there are other workarounds

Comment: you will not be able to use top_hits in an other aggregation. There are other options like using another terms aggregation. Hard to tell without knowing what is being done in  bucket script